# How to unpartition a table and keep the data

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, partitioning, database-administration

On a Oracle 19c database I'm migrating a table partitioned by range that has a bunch of detail tables partitioned by reference. Because of some legacy complexity it would be easiest to un-partition that table, keeping all existing data. How can I do this?

I can merge all existing partitions into one partition but that still means the table is partitioned (for eg. I can't create a new partition with the same name).

Here's what I tried:

1. Using DBMS_REDEFINITION on the master table with an interim table that is not partitioned. But start_redef_table is failing with " ORA-23549: table involved in reference partitioning"
2. Using DBMS_REDEFINITION on the detail tables failed with the same error
3. Dropping the foreign key constraints on the detail tables (so I could then run DBMS_REDEFINITION on the tables). This failed with "ORA-14650: operation not supported for reference-partitioned tables"

Comment: You'll have to unpartition (CTAS to new tables) the detail tables, then do the same to the parent table. Then renames and apply dependent (index, grants, etc..) DDL.

Comment: @PaulW I was hoping to rely on DBMS_REDEFINITION package to be sure I don't miss any dependent objects. Are you saying that's not possible? Thanks

Comment: I actually never use that package myself, preferring to have full control, so I can't answer that. There's nothing really special about it - it just wraps a bunch of individual steps that we have been doing manually for decades. What you're doing is pretty common maintenance, so if you can't get dbms_redefinition to play along, then I'd suggest leaving it aside and going old-school with step-by-step DDL.

Comment: @PaulW dbms_redefinition is "special" - it syncs the old & new tables so you can run the process online. CTAS is an offline process.

Comment: What would I need to copy manually? indexes, constraints, triggers, grants... What else to copy or how could I find a complete list of things that I might need to copy? I'm new to this - I thought all_dependencies might be helpful but there's nothing there for my tables

Comment: That's about it.. indexes, constraints, triggers and grants. Many tools will extract DDL for you for a table along with all dependent object DDL so it's really simple.

Comment: @Cris, okay, you've made your point. If you really trust this kind of invasive online operation and really can't do this rare one-off work in a maintenance window, then maybe it's an option. "Online" operations are rarely truly online in every respect. They often end up in blocking conditions at the very end. If they abort can make a mess. I do not trust dbms_redefinition and it's not hard to get an hour of down time for a table during some off-business hours in the majority of databases out there. And per OP, it won't work with reference partitioning. It probably has other restrictions too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick you can use: Exchange partition!

To do this:

- Merge all the partitions into one
- Create empty, non-partitioned copies of the parent and child tables. From 12.2 this is best with the `create table ... for exchange` command
- Exchange the partition with the new parent table with the `cascade` option.

Viola! The all the rows are in unpartitioned tables. See example below.

Unlike with `dbms_redefinition`, you'll need to copy over constraints, grants, etc. manually. The data are also in the new tables, so you'll need to rename them/update synonyms/change views to make this transparent to the app.

```
create table orders (
  order_id       int 
    primary key
    not null, 
  order_datetime date
    not null,
  customer_id    int 
    not null
) partition by range ( order_datetime )
  interval ( interval '1' month ) (
    partition p0 values less than ( date'2024-01-01' )
  );

create table order_items (
  order_id 
    constraint order_fk 
    references orders ( order_id ) 
    not null,
  product_id integer
    not null,
  primary key ( 
    order_id, product_id 
  ) 
) partition by reference ( order_fk );

insert into orders 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 10
)
  select x, date'2023-01-01' + x, x
  from   rws;
  
insert into order_items
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 5
)
  select order_id, x
  from   orders cross join rws;

commit;

create table orders_stage
  for exchange with table orders;
  
create table order_items_stage
  for exchange with table order_items;

alter table order_items_stage
  add constraint order_items_pk_stage
  primary key ( order_id, product_id );  
  
alter table orders_stage
  add constraint order_pk_stage
  primary key ( order_id );  

alter table order_items_stage
  add constraint order_fk_stage
  foreign key ( order_id )
  references orders_stage ( order_id ) ;
  
alter table orders
  exchange partition p0
  with table orders_stage
  cascade;

select count(*) from orders_stage;    
/*
  COUNT(*)
----------
        10
*/
select count(*) from order_items_stage;
/*
  COUNT(*)
----------
        50
*/
```

Comment: Merging all partitions is an extremely expensive operation requiring repeated, redundant data movement as many times as there are partitions. A single CTAS will do it with only one data movement and put you in the same position.

Comment: @PaulW True; the OP already mentioned merging partitions, so presumably this is already somewhat acceptable. More importantly from 18c you can merge partitions online. You just need a brief outage to rejig the names after the exchange. CTAS is a fully offline process. So while the merge & exchange method may take (much) longer overall, you can run the majority of it online. Depending on uptime requirements this may be the most viable option.